# Activate piston on command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to create an elevator where you can't see any of the redstone or pistons while in or outside of it since I want to make an actually nice-looking one for a hotel or something.
Anyways, this is my setup for one which may be impossible unless I can either use a command to move blocks (and the player) up, or activate the pistons without having to summon a redstone block:

P=Sticky Piston

D=Dirt or solid block

1=Redstone torch

(I have it set up already so the lever can switch the torches on/off and activate the outer ones, but I'm having trouble with trying to get an elevator that's larger than 4x4 blocks to raise two blocks up or higher without a ridiculously complex or confusing system.

Side view:

DDDD

PPPP

PPPP

1111

DDDD

1111

Top view (in layers)

DDDD

DDDD

DDDD

DDDD

---

PPPP

PPPP

PPPP

PPPP

---

PPPP

PPPP

PPPP

PPPP

etc. I'll be very greatful if I can get some help with this!

Comment: Actual pictures would be easier to follow than ascii art; could you take some screenshots? Also, have you tried just placing a redstone block next to the piston with a command?

Comment: Yes you're right lol that would make it a lot easier to understand. Here it is, basically (solid non-piston blocks would be on top of the second ones in the column): http://img08.deviantart.net/789e/i/2017/094/6/e/untitled_by_shelilla-db4pnia.png  &  http://img00.deviantart.net/a604/i/2017/094/5/4/untitled_by_shelilla-db4pni4.png   Pretty much I'm wondering how to get those 4 pistons in the middle to work

Answer (score 1):

`/setblock ~ ~-2 ~ redstone_block`

Activate it and 2 blocks under the command block will be a redstone block above the redstone block place another command block above the redstone block saying:

`/setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air`

From the redstone block put redstone to the pistons or better yet

`/setblock (x y z of one block under piston) redstone_block`

Comment: They said without a Redstone block

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to make the middle 4 pistons on the first layer retract, so that you can then summon redstone blocks.